# Getting last N entries from collection | Pagination problem using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I've made notifications collection and in it I put notification as per the below schema:

```
{
  userid: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId  // the user who generated this notification
  customReceivers: [String],
  time: Number, // new Date().getTime();
... other fields
}
```

Im trying to display notifications by pagination and sorting but I get a specific order.
Like first N notifications will point from **1h ago to 2 days ago** then another pagination will again show  **5h ago to 26 days ago** and so on.

Im using this query to find:

```
notificationModel.find({userid: {$in: followingList}}.sort({time: -1}).skip(pageNo * entriesPerPage).limit(entriesPerPage).then(...
```

```
followingList = [mongoose.ObjectId("60bb75c3eb840300226bd3a8"),
mongoose.ObjectId("60bb77eeeb840300226bd3ac"), ...]
```

I've tried using `sort({$natural: 1})` it didnt work

As by default the entries are saved in ascending order of time, I just need to take last N entries and reverse the array. but the order I get is different. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe sorting through **_id** can help if sorting through **time** property is not working.

```
notificationModel.find({userid: {$in: followingList}}.sort({_id: -1}).skip(pageNo * entriesPerPage).limit(entriesPerPage).then(...
```

Comment: Yes I tried this alternative but I found the solution. I'm a dumba$$

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Problem is in the statement:

notificationModel.find({userid: **{$in: followingList}}**.sort({time: -1}).skip(pageNo * entriesPerPage).limit(entriesPerPage).then(...

$in doesn't guarantee the order of the the data (be it 1 to 1 or 1 to many relations), and hence it needs to be checked by the conditions put using $cond and $eq or what I did:

1. get all the notification IDs created by people user follows
2. get details and flags like seenByUser or any other details in aggregate and there give up the condition of skip and limit

```
notifications = await notificationModel.aggregate([
            {
                $match: { _id: { $in: notificationIDs } }, // Id got from find() previously
                
            },
            {$sort: {"time": -1}},
            { $skip: (pageNo - 1) * entriesPerPage },
            { $limit: entriesPerPage },
}
```